# How to convert a pivot back to dataframe in the same format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a pivot table out of my original dataframe

| id | label | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 0.2 |
| 2 | efg | 0.4 |
| 3 | abc | 0.2 |
| 2 | abc | 0.4 |
| 1 | efg | 0.2 |
| 3 | efg | 0.4 |

```
df.pivot(index="id", columns="label", values="value")
```

which converts the original df to:

label

| id | abc | efg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 0.4 |
| 3 | 0.2 | 0.4 |

Now I would like to convert the above dataframe back to original dataframe, reset_index() is not the option for me here.

Comment: ``df.melt('id', var_name = 'label', value_name='value')``